# Postgresql invalid byte encoding "UTF8" 0xa9

Tags: postgresql

Tried to insert Chinese character and failed. I used my MacOS to brew install the latest version 11.1 of psql, the locale was automatically set as zh_CN UTF8. Then when I tried to insert words like '店长', it showed 'invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa9'

[image: Postgresql Console]

Can anyone help fix this T^T

Comment: What is your `client_encoding`? Is the terminal you are using configured for UTF-8?